# What are differences in multitasking , multithreading between Linux Windows?

Tags: windows, linux, macos, theory

What are differences in Multitasking, Multithreading between linux, windows and Mac osx?

Comment: What is multitasking? Sounds like marketer-speak, not a technical term.

Comment: In terms of what?  Implementation?  Programming?  Performance?  Synchronization techniques?  Cross-process communication methods?  Security?

Comment: POSIX is a vendor neutral standard specification. Windows has no vendor neutral specification (and perhaps has no specification precise enough so that another variant could be developed and still remain source compatible). Unix (from which POSIX appeared) was multi-tasked from day one (late 1970-s). Windows 3.11 was probably single-tasked. Most importantly, Linux is free software -you can study and improve its kernel source, Windows is proprietary -can you read its source code?-.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb496993.aspx